# Code Generating null exception TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding during CI (teamcity) execution

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, teamcity, specflow, extentreports

Code is returning below exception during execution from teamcity server. While same script is working fine on local. Issue is only from CI execution.

I tried to debug and tried to figure out something if this may help you guys. Here I have declared Extent report object in BeforeTestRun tag. Object variable is private static in same class.I'm sharing code snippet for same.

```
using AventStack.ExtentReports;
using AventStack.ExtentReports.Gherkin.Model;
using AventStack.ExtentReports.Reporter;
using BoDi;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Reflection;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;

namespace MBV.Foundation.customer.Testing.GeneralHooks
{
    [Binding]
    public class Generic
    {
        private static ScenarioContext _scenarioContext;
        private static ExtentReports _extentReports;
        private static ExtentHtmlReporter _extentHtmlReporter;
        private static ExtentTest _feature;
        private static ExtentTest _scenario;
        private readonly IObjectContainer _objectContainer;
        private IWebDriver driver;

        public Generic(IObjectContainer objectContainer)
        {
            _objectContainer = objectContainer;
        }

        [BeforeTestRun]
        public static void BeforeTestRun()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("BeforeTestRun start");
            _extentHtmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(String.Format(Constants.DataSheets.TestingOnlyReports, $"{Environment.UserName}_{System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")}"));
            _extentHtmlReporter.Configuration().Theme = AventStack.ExtentReports.Reporter.Configuration.Theme.Dark;
            _extentReports = new ExtentReports();
            _extentReports.AttachReporter(_extentHtmlReporter);
            //_extentHtmlReporter.LoadConfig(Constants.DataSheets.XmlPath);
        }

        [BeforeFeature]
        public static void BeforeFeatureStart(FeatureContext featureContext)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("BeforeFeature start");
            if (null != featureContext)
            {
                if(_extentReports != null)
                    { Console.WriteLine("anything"); }
                else
                { Console.WriteLine("not anything"); }
                _feature = _extentReports.CreateTest<Feature>(featureContext.FeatureInfo.Title, featureContext.FeatureInfo.Description);
            }
        }
```

I'm getting output of BeforeFeature as "not anything"
This is becoming null in BeforeFeatureStart tag and I'm not able to consume it hence throwing null refrence exception.
All versions are same of specflow components in project. I'm mentioning again "Same project/execution is working fine on local machine."

```
System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    at MBV.Foundation.customer.Testing.GeneralHooks.Generic.BeforeFeatureStart(FeatureContext featureContext) in C:\BuildAgent\work\79c82bdb2de10fc1\src\Foundation\Testing\customer\GeneralHooks\Generic.cs:line 55
    at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments, ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration) in D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\Bindings\BindingInvoker.cs:line 69
    at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.InvokeHook(IBindingInvoker invoker, IHookBinding hookBinding, HookType hookType) in D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\Infrastructure\TestExecutionEngine.cs:line 352
    at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.FireEvents(HookType hookType) in D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\Infrastructure\TestExecutionEngine.cs:line 338
    at MBV.Foundation.customer.Testing.Features.ProductListingPageFeature.FeatureSetup()
```

This should work on CI (teamcity) as well. Because same is working on local machine.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code generating the error. You can find that out from the stack trace.

Comment: I edited my question. One more observation, "BeforeTestSuite" tag is not working in code. I guess this could be one reason of above error. But I don't know why this tag is not working.

Comment: The error message and stack trace is good, but we also need to see code

Comment: [BeforeTestRun]
        public static void BeforeTestRun()
        {
            _extentHtmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter("File Name Path");
            _extentReports = new ExtentReports();
            _extentReports.AttachReporter(_extentHtmlReporter);
        }

        [BeforeFeature]
        public static void BeforeFeatureStart(FeatureContext featureContext)
        {
                if(_extentReports == null)
                { Console.WriteLine("not anything"); }
        } //output "not anything". Which means _extentReports is null and BeforeTestRun not execute.

Comment: Please put this code in the question. This is nigh unreadable as a blob of text in a comment

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I updated code in my question.

Comment: I see a NullReferenceException, but everything in the method checks for null... can you annotate your code with which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: I mentioned, This is 3rd last line of entire code throwing exception. Actually "_extentReports" object is null in BeforeTestRun tag. Due to this line is throwing exception. While this object is already defined in "BeforeTestRun". I also check with If..else condition so I'm getting "not anything" output from 4th last line.